# Creating screens(windows) without JFrame

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe, screen

I have been looking at the source code of Notch's game Metagun as a guide to making my own. I noticed he never implements JFrame as a means of making a screen for the game to run in. I can't make any sense of his Screen class because I only see a drawImage method for some strings. What other ways can you create a window besides using JFrame in Java?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to create windows in Java, but for a game, I believe you're looking for a window without decoration. I'll point you then to [`JWindow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html), but it's more rudimentary...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source I found on github, he [extends Applet and Runnable](https://github.com/alexnick/metagun/blob/master/src/com/mojang/metagun/Metagun.java#L14) and creates a generic JFrame within [Metagun.main](https://github.com/alexnick/metagun/blob/master/src/com/mojang/metagun/Metagun.java#L141).